# Ignore Django Model fields in migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create a Django model that contains a `FileField` to store image and video files, but I want to validate the files before saving the instance. I've thought about adding three fields:

- `file`: A `FileField` field. This will only be used to have a `file` column in the database, but serializers won't use it (instead they will use the two next fields).
- `file_image`: An `ImageField` to perform image file validation. Before the model instance is saved, the file will be assigned to the `file` field. **I don't want this field to have a dabatase representation**.
- `file_video`: A `VideoField` (custom field) to perform video file validation. Before the model instance is saved, the file will be assigned to the `file` field. **I don't want this field to have a dabatase representation**.

Of course, `file_image` and `file_video` won't be set at the same time.

The problem is preventing `makemigrations` from including `file_image` and `file_video` in the migrations. I could edit the migration file by hand, but I wonder if there is any way to automatically ignore these fields.

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField()
    file_image = models.ImageField()    # Not an actual column
    file_video = models.VideoField()    # Not an actual column

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.file_image.file is not None:
            self.file.file = self.file_image.file
        elif self.file_video.file is not None:
            self.file.file = self.file_video.file
        else:
            raise ValidationError()

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: why not create `file_image` and `file_video` inside `save()` method?

Comment: I want to map `file_image` and `file_video` directly from a DRF serializer and benefit from the image/video validation that `ImageField`/`VideoField` already performs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is a representation of what's in the database. I would advise you not to fight against the ORM in this manner. Instead, I would perform the validation within the form class that's used when creating/updating the instance. With the form you can define the fields, `file_video` and `file_image`, then whichever is used, use that field to write to `file`.

Comment: I don't have a form for my model, and I haven't needed it so far. But I do have a custom form field for `VideoField` and the built-in for `ImageField` that perform the validations. I don't exactly know how I would do what you say, but it seems like a lot of work.
I'm building a REST API with DRF. My idea was using two `serializers.FileField` for `file_audio` and `file_video` in the serializer.

Comment: Yes, you can do the same there. Have two writable fields, one that's tailored for video the other for images. Have validation that they both aren't used. Then when saving/updated, update the `file` instance.

Comment: I don't really want to add custom fields to my serializer to validate the files. I would prefer a validation in the model to also validate files when using the ORM.
I just posted an answer with a solution based (partially at least) in your answer. Is it near to what you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I abandoned my original idea of adding extra fields to the model and I only left `file` field, as suggested by @schillingt. Now I'm using a custom validation in the `clean()` method to validate the file type.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageFieldFile
from django import forms

from custom_fields import forms as custom_forms
from custom_fields import fields as custom_fields


class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField()

    def clean(self):
        # Get the MIME type to have a hint of the file type
        import magic
        mime_type = magic.from_buffer(self.file.file.read(1024), mime=True)

        if mime_type.startswith('image'):
            image_field = ImageFieldFile(self, models.ImageField(),
                                         self.file.name)
            image_field.file = self.file.file
            if image_field.width:
                self.width = image_field.width
                self.height = image_field.height
                self.media_type = mime_type
            else:
                raise ValidationError({'file': forms.ImageField.
                                      default_error_messages['invalid_image']})

        elif mime_type.startswith('video'):
            video_field = custom_fields.VideoFieldFile(self,
                                                       custom_fields.VideoField(),
                                                       self.file.name)
            video_field.file = self.file.file
            if video_field.width:
                self.width = video_field.width
                self.height = video_field.height
                self.duration = video_field.duration
                self.media_type = mime_type
            else:
                raise ValidationError({'src': custom_forms.VideoField.
                                      default_error_messages['invalid_video']})

        else:
            raise ValidationError({'src': 'The file is neither an image nor a video.'})


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I know it's an ugly solution, but could this work? I mean, I tested it and it seems to work, but surely there will be a better and more elegant way.